# Can vscode locate files from global filesystem index(mdfind, locate, everything)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

All three major os(Windows, Linux, MacOS) have a tool for quick file serach(everything, locate, mdfind). QtCreator has nice integration with them. I can simply type `md <FILENAME>` in locator and get the file open immediately. Is there the VSCode plugin that does the same thing - utilizes global filesystem index for quick file locating?

[image]